# Does Win 10 Recovery Disk Get "Outdated"

Tags: windows-10, recovery

I am running Win 10 Pro.
I created a recovery disk more than a year ago.
I wish to do a re-install of Win 10.
Since Win 10 has been updated several times since I created the recovery disk, I am wondering if I should be making a new recovery disk before re-installing.

Comment: I can understand that the Recovery Tools may not change. However, what about a reinstall using the recovery disk? Will it install the version when the disk was created, or will the latest version be downloaded? Or am I better off creating an installation disk of the latest version and doing an install with that. FWIW I will be doing a clean install i.e. wiping the HDD completely.

Comment: According to this article [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026852/windows-create-a-recovery-drive) my initial concerns appear to be valid i.e. it does get "outdated".

Comment: @Cyber.Cynic I personally just do a clean install every time. If your internet is fast, it will only take ~7 minutes to create a bootable USB drive with a completely up-to-date version of the Windows 10 installer: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10 A reset is more convenient, making it a good option for many people, but if you are comfortable with backing up your data and have an 8 GB (or larger) flash drive, you may wish to consider the slightly more thorough clean install option.

Comment: @wrecclesham. Thanks for your input. That is exactly my intention. I have now figured out my Recovery Drive/Disk that I created more than a year ago contains an earlier version of windows and I need to create an installation media usb drive.

Comment: @Ramhound. I do believe we are talking about 2 different things. You are talking about the recovery options within the OS, whereas I an referring to a USB recovery drive/disk as described in my earlier comment. Anyhow I am now clear on how to proceed for an up to date clean install.

Comment: There is absolutely no confusion on my part.  I know exactly what your asking about.  Recovery disks do not get outdated.

Comment: Then I guess we agree to differ. Per Microsoft: Windows updates to improve security and PC performance periodically so it is recommended to recreate the recovery drive annually.

Answer (score 0):

> It's a good idea to create a recovery drive.

You already have a recovery drive.

> I created a recovery disk more than a year ago. I wish to do a re-install of Windows 10.

You can reinstall Windows using the WinRE (Windows Recovery Environment) within the Advanced Options which would transisition you to the WinPE (Windows Preinstallation Environment). What is installed would be based on the windows image (i.e. install.wim) contained on the recovery media.

> I am wondering if I should be making a new recovery disk before re-installing.

WinRE has not received any significant changes since you created the disk.  There are some new features in the future that will be added but they have neither been announced or released. Since you are looking to install Windows 10, creating a new recovery disk, would not really be helpful in that endeavor.

> am I better off creating an installation disk of the latest version and doing an install with that.

It would be easier to just use the Reset feature to accomplish your goal.  What is easier depends entirely on what version of Windows 10 you plan to run.

I would mount the ISO, for whatever version of Windows 10 I wanted to install, and when prompted for what I wanted to keep I would select the option that would result in nothing being kept.

> According to this article link my initial concerns appear to be valid i.e. it does get "outdated".

A recovery media does not become out of date.  Your recovery media does not contain personal files, since it is not an image of your system, but is infact the WinRE.  However, your recovery media, can be used to reinstall Windows 10.  The image used to perform this task will be specific to the install.wim that is contained on the drive.  You can use this image, which will install an older version of Windows 10, that could simply be updated after it's installed.

> To reinstall Windows 10, select Advanced Options > Recover from a
>   drive. This will remove your personal files, apps and drivers you
>   installed, and changes you made to settings.

Source: [Recovery options in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question,I will quote Microsoft from this link[Create a recovery drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026852/windows-create-a-recovery-drive):
It's a good idea to create a recovery drive. That way, if your PC ever experiences a major issue such as hardware failure, you'll be able to use the recovery drive to reinstall Windows 10. Windows updates to improve security and PC performance periodically so it is recommended to recreate the recovery drive annually. Personal files and any applications that did not come with your PC will not be backed up. You'll need a USB drive that's at least 16 gigabytes.